# Django: prevent deleting child model unless parent model is deleted

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models (I left out the `__str__` representation for the sake of simplicity).

`Customer`:

```
# models.py

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
                                     editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

and `Device_group`:

```
# models.py

class Device_group(models.Model):
    group_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
                                  editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Each `Customer` can only have 1 `Device_group` that is default. I want to be able to prevent the default group from being deleted when the `Customer` still exists. However, when the `Customer` is deleted, all device groups, including the default group should be deleted.

To prevent the default group from being deleted I use the pre_delete signal like this:

```
# signals.py

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Device_group)
def protect_default_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_default:
        raise ProtectedError('The default group cannot be deleted.', instance)
```

This raises a `ProtectedError` and prevents deletion when the user tries to delete the default group from the `Device_group` model in Django Admin.

To make sure all device groups, including the default group, are deleted upon deletion of the `Customer`, I tried to use another pre_delete signal to change the `is_default` field to False and delete the group like this:

```
# signals.py

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Customer)
def unprotect_default_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    default_group = Device_group.objects.get(customer_uuid=instance, is_default=True)                                         
    default_group.is_default=False
    default_group.delete()
```

When trying to delete a `Customer` who has a default `Device_group`, it results in the `ProtectedError`.

How do I make sure that upon deletion of the `Customer` **always** **all** device groups are deleted without throwing the `ProtectedError`. But deleting a `Device_group` is prevented when it is the default group?

I am using Python 3.7.2 and Django 2.1.7

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `on_delete` action:

```
customer_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Then tweak your signal.

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Customer)
def unprotect_default_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Device_group.objects.filter(customer_uuid=instance,
    is_default=False).delete()
```

Comment: Initially the device group is `is_default=True`

Comment: So just `Device_group.objects.filter(customer_uuid=instance).delete()` will do

Comment: But if you want to make sure that all groups are setted as no default, you can do `Device_group.objects.filter(customer_uuid=instance).update(is_default=False)`. But you should not have do it.

Answer (score 0):

After `default_group.is_default=False` you need to save it by `default_group.save()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried just saving like you suggested and saving before calling the `default_group.delete()`. Both still result in the `ProtectedError`.